# PostgreSQL Default Permissions not applying to other users

Tags: sql, postgresql, privileges

I am a beginner to the world of RDBMS and have started my dive at work with PostgreSQL using PgAdmin 4. I have been tasked to manage the database for my team and have started learning about permissions.

I have stumbled across the Default privileges property for schemas. I understood that the privileges defined here apply to any objects created within the schema. I have created a group role for the Admin (which I am currently the sole member of) of the team database in case I change role or whatever in the future. This way a new user can be added to this Admin group without having to manually add them to the permissions to each individual object if I should leave. All permissions (including GRANT) have been applied as default table permissions to this Admin group for all schemas.

However, I have found that when other users that have CREATE permissions add new tables to schemas, the default privileges are not being applied. Even as the owner of the schema I cannot see or access any of the properties of the tables my teammates are creating. I have had to ask the SuperUser account to manually add me to be able to fix the permissions on these tables.

My questions is: why are the default permissions I have defined not being applied to objects created to other users. Is there a way to ensure all users adhere to the same set of default permissions?

Here are the SQL statement I have been using:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "schema_name" TO "user_1"

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA "schema_name" TO "user_1"

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "schema_name"
GRANT ALL ON TABLES TO "admin_me" WITH GRANT OPTION;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "schema_name"
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO "user_1";

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "schema_name"
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO "user_2";
```

where `admin_me` is the group where I am in, and `user_1` and `user_2` are not part of the admin_me group.

Thanks!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the CREATE ROLE and ALTER statements you have been using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the suggestion. I have included a sample of the SQL code I have used (taken from PgAdmin 4 automatically generated SQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Laurenz Albe for explaining Default Priviliges. I managed to find a solution to my problem using Event Triggers (also thanks to Laurenz Albe). I created an Event Trigger to react to `CREATE TABLE` tags and execute a Trigger Function to grant the "default" permissions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_create_table_func()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE obj record;
BEGIN
    FOR obj IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() WHERE command_tag in ('CREATE TABLE')
        LOOP
            EXECUTE format('GRANT ALL ON TABLE %s TO "admin_me" WITH GRANT OPTION;', obj.object_identity);
            EXECUTE format('GRANT SELECT ON TABLE %s TO "team_group";', obj.object_identity);
        END LOOP;
END;
$$;

CREATE EVENT TRIGGER trg_create_table ON ddl_command_end
WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_create_table_func();
```

Comment: If that is all you wanted (I didn't get that from your question), then you should use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`. That is much simpler.

Comment: Wouldn't every user who creates tables have to run that command on every table they create in order to accomplish the same?

Comment: You need one `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` per user that creates tables. That is all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding here: privileges on a schema do **not** determine or influence permissions or ownership of tables in that schema.

If user A is a member of the `admin` group, and that group has the `CREATE` privilege on the schema, user A can create a table in that schema. **But that table will belong to A, not to `admin`.**

Now only the owner of a table or the superuser can `ALTER` or `DROP` the table of `GRANT` permissions on it. That is why `admin` and other users in that group cannot change permissions on the table.

If all you need is to change permissions, you could run the following as user A:

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE newtab TO admin WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Then any member of `admin` can manage permissions on that table. There is no such option to delegate `ALTER TABLE` or `DROP TABLE` to others.

Comment: My goal is to ensure that a set of privileges are applied automatically when a user with `CREATE` permissions creates a new table in a schema. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Automatically: perhaps you can use an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After a lot of readings I managed to implement a solution using Event Triggers.